# Wikitude: How to load JQuery in HTMLDrawables

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

We are using ARchitect and Wikitude in this augmented reality app in android. Basically we want to add additional capabilities to the html. So we want to add jquery flavors on it.

We are trying to load JQuery inside the HTML drawable but it is not working.

When we load the html file to the normal browser, it is working well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

We tried using this two codes but nothing happens.

Comment: html drawable? do you mean webview?

Comment: nope, this is in ARchitect and Wikitude

Comment: Ok, I dont know then, maybe the second line? its a relative URL, when packaged in apk this could be a problem.. not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, after getting the JQuery library calling path correct.
Meaning in this case moving the downloaded JQuery library file (jquery-1.9.1.js) into the same folder in Eclipse project as where the HTML files using JQuery are, when script calling line looks like this:
`<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`